# Image processing - Brightness and Contrast

Tags: c, colors, sdl, rgb

I'm trying to adjust the brightness and contrast of an image. I had a look at the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) for conversions of RGB to HSL/HSV then adjusting and converting back, but that produces really weird outputs. So now I'm looking at [other examples](http://thecryptmag.com/Online/56/imgproc_5.html) and it seems to be working fine.. The only problem is how can I adjust brightness and contrast at the same time?

So say I have RGB of 100 100 100, then I want to adjust brightness to double and contrast to half... 2 and 0.5. How would I go about that? According to the second link, I would add 100 to all RGB values for brightness and then plug in these new RGB values into the contrast formulae?

Anyone have any ideas?

P.S - This is in C working with SDL and raw RGB values.

Comment: what do you mean by weird output?

Comment: The colours are really off for some reason, it might be because I am using 8 bit colours (Uint8).

Comment: That should be normal, but i guess for the conversion you should use floating point because there are some calculations in there, i expect to be some divisions right?

Comment: Yep, I use doubles when converting, then round back when going back to RGB.

Comment: then it should be okay, but wikipedia says that in this model there are problems, like shifting colors can make the image also look brighter or darker...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this answers your question, but you are using 8 bits color pictures, which are usually either using a palette of *n*bits colors or splitting the 8 bits into something like 3 red, 3 green and 2 blue.

Assuming you are using palettes, you might have to call [SDL_SetPalette](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetpalette.html) as your operations will change the colors.

If you're splitting in 3/3/2 bits, keep in mind that this means that there are only 8 discrete values for red, 8 discrete values for green and 4 discrete values for blue. Changes in colors might look weird in this case.

If only the source is 8 bits, I would suggest converting it to 24/32 bits after loading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to work in a space such as HSV.  Particularly you're interested in value (V).  See this link for formulas to convert from RGB to HSV/HSL and vica versa.  The code is javascript but it's elementary to convert to C. 
http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c

Another thing to consider is Luminance (Y) and Luma (Y')
I usually use the following formula for luminance.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28relative%29

```
Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B
```

I'm not sure what's best to use: V, Y, or Y'.  Wiki says "the definition of a lightness or value dimension is less obvious: there are several possibilities depending on the purpose and goals of the representation."  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness

I have been using Y.  The difference between Y and Y' is due to gamma correction.  As long as you account for it properly I think you can use either.  But maybe you can simply use V for your contrast and brightness.

Lastly, be careful to consider gamma correction.

Edit: Let me outline how I think the process would go.

1. Convert color components to float
2. If colors are in sRGB (which is non-linear) then convert to RGB (which is linear)
3. Convert RGB to HSV
4. Scale the value (V) to change the brightness. Change the saturation (S) as well for contrast.
5. Convert back to RGB
6. Convert RGB to sRGB if necessary.
7. Convert color components back to range [0,255].